# orm.xml named query with input parameter

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, hibernate, jpa

I am currently learning JPA with Hibernate, using maven as well.

It happens so that I need to use named query's in my orm.xml with a input parameter in the set-clausule of an update statement. It gives me an error that a parameter can only be used in the WHERE or HAVING clausule.

After reading several pages I found out that JPA 2.0 does not support it, but JPA 2.1 does.
[See this, bulletpoint 4.6.4](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_1-edr-spec/persistence-2_1-edr-spec.pdf?AuthParam=1397634145_1f9b88bb612cc4feb999e35867985009)

So I changed my orm.xml and persistence.xml to the 2.1 schemes as well, but it still gives and error. Although it still runs perfectly, I hate seeing error signs.

Anyone Any idea? I am using Eclipse Kepler 4.3.2

Pictures of orm.xml, persistence.xml, pom.xml and my project properties can be found [here](http://postimg.org/gallery/2ks1iwc4k/62e3b5db/)

Comment: Can you add some of the code (especially the query) and configuration.

Comment: Feel free to direct yourself to the bottom of my post. All pictures of code are there :). It's a basic basic query btw.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I need new glasses :)

Comment: Looks like no1 knows whats happening :p

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, code works fine and it should with JPA 2.1 (Final Release)

http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf In chapter4.6.4 (page 182) find this text (my highlight):

"Input parameters can only be used in the WHERE clause or HAVING clause of a query or as the new value for an update item in the SET clause of an update statement. "

But eclipse validation still take input parameter in update query as an error...
Maybe we should raise a bug against org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql

Answer (score 0):

The following query should work:

```xml
<named-query name = "Artikel.findByWord">
    <query>
        UPDATE Artikel a 
        SET a.verkoopprijs = a.verkoopprijs * :percentage
    </query>
</named-query>
```

with the corresponding java code:

```java
em.createNamedQuery("Artikel.findByWord")
  .setParameter("percentage", 10)
  .executeUpdate();
```

Comment: I am not telling it doesn't work. My code works perfectly, but it is giving an error, where there is none. :) (See my screenshots)